# loading google map in angular.dart view (ng-view)

Tags: google-maps, dart, angular-dart

I am trying to create a single page app in `angular.dart` with **multiple views**, but I cant find a working example of loading up a **Google Map** in a view being routed into.

I am using the `google_maps` package. It works out fine when the `div` element to contain the map is defined in the main `index.html` page, but an exception is thrown when the map div is defined in the view:

```
'TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null'
```

I suppose this means the view has not been rendered by the time the directive class is loading. How should one load a Map in a view?

**Here is the router:**

```dart
@InjectableService()
class DefaultRouteInitializer implements RouteInitializer {

  init(Router router, ViewFactory view) {
  router.root
    ..addRoute(
        name: 'city',
        path: '/city',
        enter: view('view/city_view.html'));
  }
}
```

**And the view html:**

```html
<div city-ctrl>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="city_map_canvas" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**And the Directive class having issues creating the actual map:**

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';

@NgDirective(
  selector: '[city-ctrl]'
)
class CityController {

  CityController() {
    final mapOptions = new MapOptions()
    ..zoom = 8
    ..center = new LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    ..mapTypeId = MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    ;
    final map = new GMap(querySelector("#city_map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working by letting the city-ctrl directive implement NgAttachAware interface method attach(), and initiate the Maps from there. The constructor was obviously the wrong place for that. The following worked out:

```dart
@NgDirective(
  selector: '[city-ctrl]'
)
class CityController implements NgAttachAware {

  CityController() {
  }

  attach() {    
    final mapOptions = new MapOptions()
    ..zoom = 8
    ..center = new LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    ..mapTypeId = MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    ;
    final map = new GMap(querySelector("#city_map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution proposed by Günter Zöchbauer in my @component .but It still not works(Maybe I made some mistake),after that I noticed that the my gogole map is in the shadwo dom.so I can implement the ShadowRootAware  class and it's on onShadowRoot method to show google map .because onShadowRoot method will be called untill the html elements are load.
here is the component html:

```dart
  <div id="addculture">
  ...some code 
   <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  ...some code
  </div>
```

and here is the component dart file:

```dart
  library culture_component;
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

import '../service/culture_story.dart';
import '../service/culture.dart';
import '../service/query_service.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js' show context, JsObject;
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';

@Component(selector: 'add-culture', templateUrl: '../lib/component/add_culture_component.html', cssUrl: '../lib/component/add_culture_component.css', publishAs: 'addCultureCmp')
class AddCultureComponent implements AttachAware, ShadowRootAware {



  AddCultureComponent(RouteProvider routeProvider, this.queryService, this._http) {
   //todo 

  }

  @override
  onShadowRoot(ShadowRoot shadowRoot) {
    final mapOptions = new MapOptions()
      ..zoom = 8
      ..center = new LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
      ..mapTypeId = MapTypeId.ROADMAP;
    var mapDiv = shadowRoot.querySelector("#map-canvas");
    final map = new GMap(mapDiv, mapOptions);
  }

  @override
  attach() {


  }
}
```

Comment: Is this how you solved it, or is it still not working?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to load map data in "AfterViewChecked" Lifecycle Hook and to use null-type check before loading:

```
 class MapComponent implements AfterViewChecked {

 if (document.getElementById(‘map’) == null) {
  return;
 }

 ngAfterViewChecked() {
  GMap(
   document.getElementById(‘map’),
   MapOptions()
   ..center = LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
   ..zoom = 8,
  );
 }}
```

Here is my article with step-by-step instructions:

https://medium.com/@ababenko_95981/angulardart-google-maps-inside-component-1edb708ee68c