# using google maps in an AngularDart View

Tags: google-maps-api-3, dart, angular-dart

So, I've noticed an issue with Angular Dart views where they don't want to place nice when you want to interoperate with javascript. I noticed the issue when I was working with the facebook SDK. Luckily with facebook there is a built in mechanism to load in the sdk asynchronously. Now, I am trying the same thing with google maps because of a requirement I need to meet. The poor thing keeps complaining that the maps object doesn't exist even though I include the script within the view itself.

I've even tried things like this code snippet:

In the view body I have this:

```dart
<script>
  function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&' +
      'callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    console.log("ran method");
  }
</script>
```

And in my angular controller I'm running this in the constructor:

```dart
context["initialize"] = (){
  print("Script loaded");
  map = new MapWrapper(); //map is being handled by a model class
};
context["loadScript"].callMethod();
```

The context says that "loadScript" doesn't exist even though it's in the views body. What do?

Comment: I haven't used Google Maps yet but I guess you need to pass a DOM element to the script where the map should be rendered. How do you do that?

Comment: Here is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061290 but it seems here this packages is used http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps which does the dart-js-interop for you.

Comment: I'm currently using the package, but it is complaining that the google maps api doesn't exist, which means the client is not loading the script. Is there a way to prevent angular dart from stifling the js?

Comment: I haven't seen this mentioned anywhere that Angular.dart prevents a JS script from loading. Can you try if it works when you have the `map_canvas` element outside of any angular component? I guess its caused by the shadowDOM which prevents JavaScript finding the canvas element. You could also try `useShadowDOM: false` (see https://github.com/akserg/angular.dart.ui/blob/6e455a4686cfb4d5953d10827b5fceb10128f89f/lib/alert/alert.dart#L23)

Comment: When I move, it out of the angular component it works, but that isn't my intended flow

Comment: But that mean that Angular. dart isn't preventing the script from loading but the script isn't able to find the canvas inside the shadowDOM. U can use useShadowDom: false or find a way to select the canvas element in Dart and pass it to the script.