# AngularDart View finishes loading

Tags: google-maps, dart, angular-dart

Hi I am trying to load Google Maps into a div. I have it attach itself to the div on "**onShadowRoot**" however the Div is still not properly laid out at that time. Is there another callback/future that is called when the view is full laid out?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061290

Comment: Thanks, but that does not resolve the issue.

Comment: If this doesn't work it can be usually fixed by wrapping the code in attached or oNshadowRoot with `new Future(() {your code here});`

Comment: That worked! Do you know why?

Comment: The Future allows Angular to complete the current thread of execution and delays your custom code until Angular is done. There's obviously a timing issue. This is a known issue and a known workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code in `new Future(() {your code here});`. This allows Angular to complete the current thread of execution before your code is executed.

Comment: how does it know to run an arbitrary future created in the function tho?

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for  https://www.dartlang.org/articles/event-loop/